# Tracking when a contact reaches a goal in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, event, goals

I'm attempting to track at what time a contact reaches my goal in Journey Builder in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. What I would like is to time stamp when a contact reaches a goal, and drop that either into a data extension in marketing cloud, or back into Sales Cloud (connector).

I've reviewed the documentation, and it seems like this functionality doesn't exist. Is that correct? Has anyone found a work-around? The only thing I could find was the update journey builder event under object activity. Unfortunately, for some reason I can't access those types of activities, and [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_object_activity.htm&type=5) is minimal.

Comment: The object activity would be a good solution, why can’t you access it?

Comment: @zuzannamj   Not sure. It just spins whenever I attempt to open any of the three journey activity functions under object activity. I've opened a case with SF support, so we'll see if they can figure it out. Good to know though I'm on the right track with the object activity!